# This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement react native android

Tags: google-play, react-native

I have already upgraded my React native version 0.57.1 to 0.59.1 and fix all the library issues. After successfully build i uploaded .aap file to play store but i am getting below error:

**Error
This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement
The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 21.
Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app.**

Please let me know if anyone can solve this issue Thanks!

Here is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 19
      compileSdkVersion = 28
      targetSdkVersion = 28
      supportLibVersion = "1.0.0-beta01"
      googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
```

package.json

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "^0.59.1",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add abi filters ("arm64-v8a" and "x86-64")

```
android {
    ...   

    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    // In case, if you're using `ndk`
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            // Tells Gradle to build outputs for the following ABIs and package
            // them into your APK.
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) { 
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}
    ...
```